# Reset Bash terminal output to console after directing output to file

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, make

I have a script with output I want to capture.

```
make some_args 2>../error-compile
```

I believe the error capture is working fine.

Problem is that it is an hours long compile with an install so I have something like this before the sudo install in my script.

```
echo "Please press enter to install"
read temp
sudo make install > out 2>../error-install
```

And the request for input gets ignored and I believe the script errors out.

How do I reset stdout, stdin, and stderr in Bash after directing stderr to a file?

Comment: The redirection in `make some_args 2>../error-compile` affects `make`, not the whole shell that runs it, nor commands that come after. (Unless there are unquoted/unescaped `&`, `;` or such hidden behind the term `some_args`.) Are `echo`, `read` and `sudo make` in the makefile, so you think the redirection affects them somehow?

Comment: I will check that. echo, read and sudo make are in the bash script.

Comment: [How do I write stderr to a file while using tee with a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/692000)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you were correct. There was an issue with some_args. Thank you.